# How do I inline a pointer in CPP?

Tags: c++, pointers

Hey I'm new to c++ coming from java and I can't understand how to make this:

```
std::string some_string = "some text";
string* some_pointer = &some_string;
```

all in one line. Example of what I am thinking of:

```
void some_function(string* some_pointer);

some_function(get_pointer_of("test"));
```

Comment: I think this is a place where you want to use a reference rather than a pointer. ie `void some_function(const std::string& some_str)`. I don't think it can be done in one line.

Comment: this can be done but it would be a bad practice.some_function(new std::string{"test"}); u must handle the pointer inside the function or return the address again.

Comment: You generally wouldn't want to do this inline, since if you construct a temporary string, then take the address of it, the string would then get destroyed and you would end up with a dangling pointer. You are better of using ```const char*``` and then constructing a string around that wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done but it would be a bad practice. You must handle the pointer inside the function or return the address again to handle it later.

An example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
std::string* fun(std::string * str){
    std::cout << *str;
    *str = "ff";
    return str;
}
int main(){
    auto ptr = fun( new std::string{"ee"});//u have (new std::string{"ee"}) in one line
    std::cout << "\n" << *ptr ;
    delete ptr;

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M7vh8M)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot <sup>1</sup>.

You can create temporary objects inline within expressions, but you cannot take their address directly. Conversely, you can take the address of a value inline, but you cannot do that with an rvalue.

<sup>1</sup> ... in a simple way. And you should probably avoid doing it with a complex trick.